# Specific and Broad MySQL search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page where a user can search a mysql database using 5 different input fields and each input field matches a column of a mysql table. As of now they can search the database but all fields have to match exactly what is in the table, whole bunch of LIKE and AND statements, for any results to be returned. What I want to do is if they only know the first two fields than the database returns all instances containing the given information. Also if the user fills out more than the first two fields than the query will take that into account and return all the results found matching all the information given. I looked at the weighted searches and I thought that would get me close to what I needed but it seemed to me that weighted searches will always return a result, just the more exact one will be at the top, and for what I am doing if there are no results found no results should be returned. If you guys can help me out with a way to code this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to find out which params are not empty first:

```
foreach $_POST as $param {
$params[] = $param;
}
```

then you have to make a long expression for WHERE attr:

```
$query = "";
foreach $params as $param_name=>$param {
$query .= " && ".$param_name."=".$param;
}
// output: " && age=15 && gender=female && eyes=brown"
```

and finaly making a SELECT without "&&" at the begining:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE".substr($query,3);
```

Comment: Hey sunny I am totally new to MySQL and PHP and this is the first time I have ever seen foreach or $param but I think I get the jist of it. Please correct me if I am not following correctly. So the first bit of code is basically taking the posted field information and putting them into a an array called $params. The second piece of code is than taking that array and putting each indexed field and putting it into a usable MySQL query string and the third bit of code takes the $query variable and puts it into a select statement. If I am wrong on any of this and you don't mind please let me know.

Comment: Yes. You have understood it as well.

Comment: Hey sunny I appreciate the help. It took a little extra work and had learn some new things but I was able to get it to work exactly how I needed it too and you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Build up the query in parts with PHP, and add the parts you need if a value exists. So something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1";
$sql = .= (if(isset($_POST['field1']) && $_POST['field1'])?' AND field1='{$_POST['field1']}':'';
//etc
```

Obviously this is a basic example, and should not be used as is. You must ensure you are sanitising the user supplied input before you use it in a query.